# Is facial recognition possible using android Camera.face api?

Tags: android

As of API level 14 android introduced the Camera.Face api.  This api provides you with the following fields:

```
int id  - An unique id per face while the face is visible to the tracker.

Point leftEye - The coordinates of the center of the left eye.

Point mouth - The coordinates of the center of the mouth.

Rect rect - Bounds of the face.

Point rightEye - The coordinates of the center of the right eye.

int score -The confidence level for the detection of the face.
```

My question is, using these properties is it possible to create a database/list of known faces along with their attributes and then match new faces that show up to known faces?

Answer (score 3):

No, its not possible with that API alone. [Facial recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_recognition_system) and [face detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_detection) are two different technologies.

The amount of info garnered from a face detection algorithm is too simplistic to be applied to a recognition algorithm. The best you could do is use the bounding rectangle to further analyze the image.

Comment: I understand they are different. I just didn't know if the data given in android's face detection could be utilized to create facial recognition